# What will happen, In main method of a class, If you instantiate a class and call the wait() on its own instance?.

Tags: java

I have my a class and in its main method I create a instance of the same class and I call wait method on that instance what will happen in that case?

Comment: What happens when you try this? We're a poor substitute for your compiler and JVM.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

Comment: @Ingo Does not detect what situation? Throws what exception? How can it throw an exception if it doesn't detect the situation?

Comment: @EJP I mean dead lock. For example, in the GHC (Haskell) runtime, the scheduler notes deadlocks and terminates the program. While the JVM just sits there.

Answer (score 2):

It will just wait forever: http://ideone.com/bjUe6Y

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.setErr(System.out);
        System.out.println("Start");
        Ideone i = new Ideone();
        synchronized (i)
        {
            i.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public Ideone() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Instanciated");
    }
}
```

---

However, if you don't synchronize on the object, it will throw an `IllegalMontiorStateException`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at Ideone.<init>(Main.java:20)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:14)
```

http://ideone.com/ceZYTQ  (wait inside the constructor)

Comment: No, you didn't. From the docs: "IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor". I see no synchronized in your code ....

Comment: @Ingo: Thank you! I learned something new.